# RPi.GPIO library working in python 3.4 but not in python 2.7

Tags: python, pi-3, rpi.gpio

I am using raspberry pi model 3.
I was exploring RPi.GPIO library and I realized that the **code shown below works in python 3.4 but not in python 2.7**. *The worst part is I am not getting any error messages when I run in python 2.7 which makes it difficult to trace the error.* I tried to search for support online, but couldn't get any decent resource.
Could anyone provide me a solution or resource to make this code work in python 2.7?

```
# LED Blinks (Python3)
# The code will turn ON LED for a second and turn OFF LED for a second in a infinite loop

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(12, 1)
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(12,0)
        sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include full details of any error messages?

Comment: The code as presented works in both Python 2 (2.7) and Python 3 (3.4) on my jessie Pi3 system.

Comment: Can you add a `GPIO.setwarnings(True)` before `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.Board)` and see if any warnings are shown ?

Comment: GPIO.output(12,True)
GPIO.output(12,False)
Will work...

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the **`1`** with **`GPIO.HIGH`** and **`0`** with **`GPIO.LOW`** like so

```
# LED Blinks (Python3)
# The code will turn ON LED for a second and turn OFF LED for a second in a infinite loop

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

## Notes

Within the [source](https://pypi.python.org/packages/c1/a8/de92cf6d04376f541ce250de420f4fe7cbb2b32a7128929a600bc89aede5/RPi.GPIO-0.6.2.tar.gz#md5=9db86fd5f3bae872de9dbb068ee0b096) archive,
is a file `source/constants.c` which contains the following function definition

```
void define_constants(PyObject *module)
{
   high = Py_BuildValue("i", HIGH);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "HIGH", high);

   low = Py_BuildValue("i", LOW);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "LOW", low);

   output = Py_BuildValue("i", OUTPUT);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "OUT", output);

   input = Py_BuildValue("i", INPUT);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "IN", input);

   pwm = Py_BuildValue("i", PWM);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "HARD_PWM", pwm);

   serial = Py_BuildValue("i", SERIAL);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "SERIAL", serial);

   i2c = Py_BuildValue("i", I2C);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "I2C", i2c);

   spi = Py_BuildValue("i", SPI);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "SPI", spi);

   unknown = Py_BuildValue("i", MODE_UNKNOWN);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "UNKNOWN", unknown);

   board = Py_BuildValue("i", BOARD);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "BOARD", board);

   bcm = Py_BuildValue("i", BCM);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "BCM", bcm);

   pud_off = Py_BuildValue("i", PUD_OFF + PY_PUD_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "PUD_OFF", pud_off);

   pud_up = Py_BuildValue("i", PUD_UP + PY_PUD_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "PUD_UP", pud_up);

   pud_down = Py_BuildValue("i", PUD_DOWN + PY_PUD_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "PUD_DOWN", pud_down);

   rising_edge = Py_BuildValue("i", RISING_EDGE + PY_EVENT_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "RISING", rising_edge);

   falling_edge = Py_BuildValue("i", FALLING_EDGE + PY_EVENT_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "FALLING", falling_edge);

   both_edge = Py_BuildValue("i", BOTH_EDGE + PY_EVENT_CONST_OFFSET);
   PyModule_AddObject(module, "BOTH", both_edge);
}
```

the constant `HIGH` is defined in `source/c_gpio.h` like so

```
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW  0
```

My best **guess** is internally within python 2.7 there is a object **reference comparison** to 
`GPIO.HIGH` to set the pin HIGH rather a **value comparison** to the contant `HIGH` (equal to 1)
and somehow this has changed (to value comparison rather than reference comparison) within python 3.
So when passing `1` works for python 3 and not with 2.7

---

## Update 1

I looked at the samples over [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/) and nowhere is a `1` constant used in place of GPIO.HIGH or `0` for GPIO.LOW which is probably why it works.

---

## Update 2 : Further Digging

Looking over the `source/py_gpio.c` lines 331 through 480

```
static PyObject *py_output_gpio(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
   unsigned int gpio;
   int channel = -1;
   int value = -1;
   int i;
   PyObject *chanlist = NULL;
   PyObject *valuelist = NULL;
   PyObject *chantuple = NULL;
   PyObject *valuetuple = NULL;
   PyObject *tempobj = NULL;
   int chancount = -1;
   int valuecount = -1;

   int output(void) {
      if (get_gpio_number(channel, &gpio))
          return 0;

      if (gpio_direction[gpio] != OUTPUT)
      {
         PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT");
         return 0;
      }

      if (check_gpio_priv())
         return 0;

      output_gpio(gpio, value);
      return 1;
   }

   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &chanlist, &valuelist))
       return NULL;

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
   if (PyLong_Check(chanlist)) {
      channel = (int)PyLong_AsLong(chanlist);
#else
   if (PyInt_Check(chanlist)) {
      channel = (int)PyInt_AsLong(chanlist);
#endif
      if (PyErr_Occurred())
         return NULL;
      chanlist = NULL;
   } else if (PyList_Check(chanlist)) {
      // do nothing
   } else if (PyTuple_Check(chanlist)) {
      chantuple = chanlist;
      chanlist = NULL;
   } else {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Channel must be an integer or list/tuple of integers");
       return NULL;
   }

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
   if (PyLong_Check(valuelist)) {
       value = (int)PyLong_AsLong(valuelist);
#else
   if (PyInt_Check(valuelist)) {
       value = (int)PyInt_AsLong(valuelist);
#endif
      if (PyErr_Occurred())
         return NULL;
       valuelist = NULL;
   } else if (PyList_Check(valuelist)) {
      // do nothing
   } else if (PyTuple_Check(valuelist)) {
      valuetuple = valuelist;
      valuelist = NULL;
   } else {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Value must be an integer/boolean or a list/tuple of integers/booleans");
       return NULL;
   }

   if (chanlist)
       chancount = PyList_Size(chanlist);
   if (chantuple)
       chancount = PyTuple_Size(chantuple);
   if (valuelist)
       valuecount = PyList_Size(valuelist);
   if (valuetuple)
       valuecount = PyTuple_Size(valuetuple);
   if ((chancount != -1 && chancount != valuecount && valuecount != -1) || (chancount == -1 && valuecount != -1)) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Number of channels != number of values");
       return NULL;
   }

   if (chancount == -1) {
      if (!output())
         return NULL;
      Py_RETURN_NONE;
   }

   for (i=0; i<chancount; i++) {
      // get channel number
      if (chanlist) {
         if ((tempobj = PyList_GetItem(chanlist, i)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
         }
      } else { // assume chantuple
         if ((tempobj = PyTuple_GetItem(chantuple, i)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
         }
      }

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
      if (PyLong_Check(tempobj)) {
         channel = (int)PyLong_AsLong(tempobj);
#else
      if (PyInt_Check(tempobj)) {
         channel = (int)PyInt_AsLong(tempobj);
#endif
         if (PyErr_Occurred())
             return NULL;
      } else {
          PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Channel must be an integer");
          return NULL;
      }

      // get value
      if (valuecount > 0) {
          if (valuelist) {
             if ((tempobj = PyList_GetItem(valuelist, i)) == NULL) {
                return NULL;
             }
          } else { // assume valuetuple
             if ((tempobj = PyTuple_GetItem(valuetuple, i)) == NULL) {
                return NULL;
             }
          }
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
          if (PyLong_Check(tempobj)) {
             value = (int)PyLong_AsLong(tempobj);
#else
          if (PyInt_Check(tempobj)) {
             value = (int)PyInt_AsLong(tempobj);
#endif
             if (PyErr_Occurred())
                 return NULL;
          } else {
              PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Value must be an integer or boolean");
              return NULL;
          }
      }
      if (!output())
         return NULL;
   }

   Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

line number 468

```
if (PyErr_Occurred())
    return NULL;
```

checks for errors and silently returns NULL. this might explain why no errors where reported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried changing the **1** constant used in place of **GPIO.HIGH** and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I checked this program on Raspbian Wheezy(Python 2 and Python3) and Raspbian Jessie(Python2 and Python3). It works very well. I didn't used Keyboard interrupt in this program. From my previous experience Keyboard interrupt put me in trouble. I am now sticking with BCM numbering of Raspberry Pi. The GPIO#12 is GPIO18 according to BCM numbering. We know that we are using while(True) instead while(1) to produce infinite loops. Here we are using True instead 1 or HIGH and False instead 0 or LOW.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
while True:
    GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Removing warnings
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(18, True)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
```

According to me it is unnecessary to add keyboard interrupt for this one.